# IPython event handler

Tags: python, ipython

Is there any event in IPython notebook that I can listen to when a cell is returned? I would love to add handler functions (such as printing some message to the user) after codes in a cell finished running.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the Python side of the JS side?

Comment: @ThomasK I want to do it on the JS side. That's correct. I am aware that there is a messaging system in place to pass information between Ipython kernel and the frontend. I am not sure how to attach callback functions to it.https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/aba5fec100d63d1c128fc43c8ec1e7dba021065e/IPython/html/static/services/kernels/js/kernel.js

Comment: An [event is triggered](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/aba5fec100d63d1c128fc43c8ec1e7dba021065e/IPython/html/static/services/kernels/js/kernel.js#L526) when the kernel becomes idle after executing something, but I'm not sure what the best way is to associate that with which cell it was running. There's another event [when you make an execute request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/aba5fec100d63d1c128fc43c8ec1e7dba021065e/IPython/html/static/services/kernels/js/kernel.js#L355), but I don't think there's one for an execute_reply.